# Python Pandas shared DataFrames across Multiprocessing Managers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have a `multiprocessing.manager.BaseManager` implementation where the shared resource is a class which returns DataFrames for various pieces of data.  The issue I'm having is that, since pandas is not thread-safe, the processes are sharing instances of the data they're manipulating.  This is causing Python to crash on me.

What I've tried doing is over-riding the `MakeProxyType` method (see: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8c83c23fa32405aa9212f028d234f4129d105a23/Lib/multiprocessing/managers.py#L938) in the multiprocessing managers class to do this:

```
for meth in exposed:
    if meth.startswith("load"):
        exec('''def %s(self, *args, **kwds):
        return self._callmethod(%r, args, kwds).copy()''' % (meth, meth), dic)
    else:
        exec('''def %s(self, *args, **kwds):
        return self._callmethod(%r, args, kwds)''' % (meth, meth), dic)
```

However, it's not actually giving me copies of the data.  When I look at the output variables I'm seeing some are sharing the same memory addresses (denoted by having the same # of asterisks by them):

```
Thread 1: 0xa225630 ***
Thread 2: 0xa245518 *
Thread 3: 0xa225518 *
Thread 4: 0xa225518 *
Thread 5: 0xa2284a8
Thread 6: 0xa225550 **
Thread 7: 0xa245550 **
Thread 8: 0xa245630 
Thread 9: 0xa225630 ***
```

Which is then causing an issue when I try to manipulate the data with pandas inside the processes.

Can anyone help me out here?  Any ideas on how to force the multiprocessing manager to give me unique instances of these DataFrames so that I can avoid crashing python?  The multiprocessing manager seems like a really great class - but the documentation on it is pretty thin.

Comment: Interestingly, when I call the functions that return data in One Thread - they're all different.  When I call those functions within separate processes, some are the same...  this is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm still not 100% what the issue was here but there's an undocumented class in the `multiprocessing` library called `ThreadPool` (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py).  Not only does it have the benefit of less overhead to spin up a thread than a process, but the manager now returns distinct copies of each `DataFrame`!